# Difference of two Linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I have two linked list L1 and L2.L1 contain multiple email address (Random Order) and L2 contain multiple Spam email address(Also in Random order). Now I had to remove all spam email from Linked list L1 which is present in L2.

I have tried doing it in O(n2). And I want it to achieve it in O(n)

Comment: Are the lists sorted?

Comment: no, they are in random order.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches will be using dictionary or unordered_map.
Iterate through your L2 linked list and make a key: value pair where the key represents data of the node(spam address) and value will be the number of its occurrence.

Now use the lookup table to check for the data present in both linked list by checking for value > 0 and then delete it by shifting node pointer one step ahead.

Time complexity: O(n)
Space complexity: O(n)